# Database Table conception [SQL]

Tags: sql, database-design

as the title states, i do have a question about Table conceptions in SQL.

Let's say you have an `Suppliers` Table with the following attributes:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Street
4. Number

as it the case you always are going to save those four things, but for some suppliers an additional attribute is required:

5. Date

**Issue:** By adding `Date` to the original table, many entries are going to have `Date` as `null` since this attribute for overwhelming suppliers doesn't have any importance.

**Question**: Should you add the `5.Date` attribute to the original suppliers table, and keep for many suppliers `Date` as `null`? Or should you create a **new** table parallel to the `Suppliers` Table with this additional, for all the suppliers that do have this attribute, that is going to look like this:

`DifferentSuppliers` - Table

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Street
4. Number
5. Date

**Additional Information:** Certain suppliers let's say from the City: **ExampleCity**, can undergo a certain license test, `Date` is meant to register the date of the test. Suppliers from another city like Hamburg, are never to be tested, those the `Date` attribute doesn't have any importance for them.

Comment: What does that `Date` field contain? The actual business logic matters. A supplier may have many associated dates - date the entry was created, date after which the supplier will be valid or not valid. Sometimes it makes sense to have a `null` as there may be a legitimate business reason for not having that date. Sometimes a default is preferable.

Comment: I would definitely keep it in one table and make sure your application code deals correctly with that `null` value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, only certain suppliers, can have their licenses tested, those the `Date` is meant to register the date of the testing.

Comment: @Roman sounds like you need a separate table to hold those tests and dates, eg `SupplierLicense` or `SupplierTests`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a column that is often null. And this approach is easy to implement, which is good. But if you want to distinguish between "no licence possible/needed" and "should have a licence, but doesn't have one", you might need another approach.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, the only distinction that is going to be needed is, to find out wether the supplier did the test, since if it does have a date === it did.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, if something is only applicable to a set of entries, then make another table for it? Table like: testID, Date, SupplierID(Foreign Key) ?

Comment: Sounds like a mere column in the table is sufficient. Would you create an additional table for a middle name only because not every person has a middle name? Some columns are often null and that's totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is mandatory, of course.

BUT in my point of view you should add the `5.Date` attribute to the original suppliers table, as it stores all the proper attributes of a supplier.
In the case the supplier has this date = null it means that he does'nt need it\have it in its characteristics.

And if needed you can even perform some updates to the field in order to 'migrate' old suppliers data with the new structure.

Using 2 tables for representing the same entity would be tricky and not well designed in my advise

Answer (score 2):

You should store the date in the original suppliers table.  Why?  Because you are missing perhaps the most important column in the suppliers table:

```
SupplierId
```

This is the column that should be used for foreign key relationships.  And, as you have described the problem, all suppliers are "equal" from that perspective.  So, they should all have the same id.

What is the cost?  Most databases store `NULL` bits separately from the actual value, but both the value and the `NULL` bit is stored.  Typically dates are 4 bytes, so that is the overhead per row.  Unless you have at least millions of suppliers, the overhead for the column will be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a column named Date is too generic.  You can do better: ADDED_ON_DATE, START_DATE, EFFECTIVE_DATE, etc.  I'd add something to the column name to make its use clearer.

The recommendation of adding a surrogate, auto increment primary key is essential.

Perhaps this date is part of a larger supplier transaction history.  In that case I'd create a separate table SUPPLIER_HISTORY to represent a one-to-many collection of every supplier transaction date.

Your simple table might be too simplistic.  Your problem is most likely bigger.

The table name should be SUPPLIER, not SUPPLIERS.